# How to get page title in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Any way to **get the page title in magento**...I Have a script live person..on this I need the current page title ..So can anybodey tell me how i get the current page title?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/change-any-page-title-in-magento/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

use this code

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

you can use this code in your phtml file

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't seem to work with `->setTitle($myTitle)`

Comment: Update: I set the title in the controller instead, and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

To get the title without the Prefix (site name):

```
<?php echo str_replace(Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/title_prefix'), '', $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle()); ?>
```